# Which KSES should be used and when?

Tags: security, sanitization

The WP source shows that `wp_filter_kses` and `wp_filter_post_kses` are passed data that's "expected to be escaped with slashes."

On the other hand, `wp_kses_data` is passed data that's "expected to not be escaped" and `wp_kses_post` has code that looks like wp_kses_data.

How safe is it to pass unknown (in terms of escaped with slashes) data to these functions?

Can the first set be preferred over the second or is preferring the second set safer?

Or is this a case where you absolutely need to know the condition of your data in terms of slashed?

--update--

I'm now figuring that if you don't know whether the data is escaped you could use  `wp_kses_data( stripslashes_deep( $data ) );` and run the return though addslashes() if you need escaped in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the codex:

> wp_filter_kses should generally be
>   preferred over wp_kses_data because
>   wp_magic_quotes escapes $_GET, $_POST,
>   $_COOKIE, $_SERVER, and $_REQUEST
>   fairly early in the hook system,
>   shortly after 'plugins_loaded' but
>   earlier then 'init' or 'wp_loaded'.

The first set is then preferred. More of a question of, "is stripping slashes more secure than not?" They both use the same allowed HTML. Well yeah it depends, in absolute cases, but I would assume that it is more secure to than not to.

Basic useage of kses:

```
$filtered = wp_kses($unfiltered, $allowed_html, $allowed_protocols);
```

All of the wordpress kses functions then just do

```
$filtered = wp_kses($unfiltered, $allowedtags);
```

SO:

```
$filtered = wp_kses_data($unfiltered);
$filtered = wp_filter_kses($unfiltered); // does the same, but will also slash escape the data
```

the `post` variations use a different set of tags; those allowed for use by non-admins.

Comment: I actually wrote that part in the codex based on http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17089 ... but that's for when you **know** the data is escaped (because of wp_magic_quotes). What I don't know is what to do if you don't know the state of the data...